# Selector doesn't run in custom class object (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c

## EDITED AFTER SEVERAL INPUT COMMENTS

So i have a view controller and a helper class

```
//ViewController.h
TextFieldHelper *textFieldHelper = [[TextFieldHelper alloc] initWith:self.containerView scrollView:self.scrollView viewController:self];
[textFieldHelper runTextFieldHelper];
```

Here is my TextFieldHelper Class

```
//TextFieldHelper.h
@interface TextFieldHelper : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic) UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *activeField;

- (instancetype)initWith:(UIView *)view scrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (void)runTextFieldHelper;

@end

//TextFieldHelper.m
- (instancetype)initWith:(UIView *)view scrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
//        self.delegate = self;
    self.viewController = viewController;
    self.view = view;
    self.scrollView = scrollView;
}
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - run the text field helper
- (void)runTextFieldHelper {
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                      action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
  [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (void)hideKeyboard {
   NSLog(@"%@",@"hello world");
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Everytime i click on the view, the hideKeyboard method will not run. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: `initWithTarget:self.viewController  action:@selector(hideKeyboard)` => `initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(hideKeyboard)`

Comment: the keyboard won't hide, but no error produced anymore

Comment: What is `activeField`? It's not set in your code. `[self.view endEditing:YES];` will hide the keyboard only if one of its subview contains a firstResponder. So if `activeField` is not a subview of `self.view`...

Comment: even after there is first responder, it still wont work ...

Comment: What i want to achieve is that i dont have to call all the functions inside the textFieldHelper class again and again, that is why I create a helper class for it and then run the object from the helper class. But i couldn't achieve it. I am still struggling. sorry if I did not provide relevant codes because I am still clueless

Answer (score 1):

just replace

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.viewController
                                                                      action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
```

with

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                      action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
```

Comment: just add this     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];   in hide method

Comment: or      [viewController.view  endEditing:YES];

Comment: still not working Sir. if i move all the codes to the view controller directly, it wil lwork

Comment: try this [activeField  resignFirstResponder]

Comment: still no result... am i missing delegate or whatnot? I have added the delegate of my text field to the view controller from the interface builder